# Can we release 'malloced' memory using 'delete'?

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc, delete-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [malloc and delete in C++, opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570223/malloc-and-delete-in-c-opinions)

Can a memory obtained using the 'malloc' function call be freed using 'delete'?

I tried a simple code using a very simple structure and it seems to be working fine. But, purify reports freeing mismatched memory.

If this is a problem, how big is the problem? If such mismatched freeing of memory exists in the code is it mandatory to fix it?

Comment: Duplicate many times over, i.e. [malloc and delete in C++, opinions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570223/malloc-and-delete-in-c-opinions)

Comment: "If this is a problem, how big is the problem? If such mismatched freeing of memory exists in the code is it mandatory to fix it?" Terrible attitude, almost -1 for that alone. **Any** problem is a problem, that's it. There's should be no criteria for "this is a problem severe enough I care about it"; just *fix* it. No, you may not mix `new`/`free` or `malloc`/`delete`, *nor should you be able to*. Why are you explicitly deleting things? Wrap it up! Arg.

Comment: Sure you can do that, just don't complain when your application destroys your data :-)

Comment: @Jay: "If such mismatched freeing of memory exists in the code..." Don't you think the word "mismatched" is a hint that there is a problem?

Comment: @GMan, Since the code seems to be working fine, I wanted to know if it gets handled someway internally. The fact that I have decided to ask the Q in stack overflow shows that I do care about the problem. My question may seem stupid as I don't know C++. But, it surely is a question. Pls refrain from commenting about someone's attitude unless you know that person well. Thanks!

Comment: @Jay: The question content is independent of the attitude you expressed to it. You asked "If this is a problem, how big is the problem? If such mismatched freeing of memory exists in the code is it mandatory to fix it?" Regardless of the problem itself, this approach is broken. So I'm free to address it as I please, independent of any other aspect of your situation or personality.

Comment: @GMan, Yes. The freedom to address it as you please is ofcourse there as the freedom exists for me to express my questions in the way it pleases me. Cool. : )

Answer (score 2):

This might work on some platforms, but no you may not. It's not portable and it's an error.