# Signal 6 (SIGABRT) when assigning variable to null (C++)

Tags: c++, gdb

When analyzing a core dumped after a SIGABRT, gdb says that my last line of code executed (before entering library code) is a `NULL` assignment to a `char` pointer, as shown below:

gdb:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x006337a2 in _dl_sysinfo_int80 () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00674815 in raise () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00676279 in abort () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x006a8cca in __libc_message () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x006af55f in _int_free () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x006af93a in free () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00d0b14e in __builtin_delete () from /usr/lib/libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x0808181c in MyObject::~MyObject (this=0x84f4db0, __in_chrg=3) at ./MyObject.cpp:16
    this = (MyObject *) 0x84f4db0
```

MyObject.cpp:16 listing:

```
12: ...
13: MyObject::~MyObject() {
14:   if (this->string != NULL) {
15:     delete this->string;
16:     this->string = NULL;
17:   }
18: }
19: ...
```

First of all, I do not understand why the line 16 would result in that call stack. It would make more sense if it was a result of the execution of line 15, the one with the `delete` operator (unless "line 16" represents code executed *after* the destructor's code to free the memory allocated for that object; just guessing here).

Other than that, can anyone point the way to correctly debug that core?

Comment: it is the result of line 15.

Comment: Note that 1) the null check is superfluous since delete does it too and 2) the assignment of null is superfluous too since the object does not exist after the dtor is done. Other than that, can you create a testcase? and please post at least the error message that is emitted by glibc right before the abort. My best guess is that you wanted `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create a testcase in less than one month (the code is really big and coupled). `this->string` is of type `char *`. I don't have the error message emitted by glibc. That is all the information I have/can share.

Comment: My crystal ball is whispering that you should use `delete []`. Also that you possibly haven't followed the Rule of Three.

Comment: @molbdnilo: If you refer to my last comment, I'm sorry. That would look and feel better (or less worse) in topic bullets. :-)

Comment: Ah! About the `delete []`, please look at my comment on Kristian Duske's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type does `this->string` have? Is it a char array? Then you should use `delete [] this->string`. Is it a pointer to an object? Then that object is either already deleted and the pointer was not nulled, or the object has never been created and the pointer was left unitialized.

Comment: The type of `this->string` is `char *`. I have to tell you that that code have run for several hours (and that piece of code executed several times) before the crash. If the problem was the use of `delete` instead of `delete []`, shouldn't it crash at the first time it executes?

Comment: @freitass: When you invoke UB, anythign can happen.

Comment: @freitass "Undefined Behaviour". It's acronymed way too often around here. A program with undefined behaviour is invalid and unpredictable. Anything can happen - in particular, it might crash or it might not, or it might seem to work except on Thursdays.

Comment: @molbdnilo: your humility is terrific!

Comment: @PlasmaHH and @Kristian Duske: I think you were at the correct path. That array was allocated with `malloc` -- inside the function `strdup` -- which, on the other hand, should be deallocated with `free`, is that right? (Yes, there is a lot of C code mixed up with C++; and no, the code is not mine, which explains the fact that it took me a little while to notice the `malloc` thing.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570223/should-a-warning-or-perhaps-even-an-assertion-failure-be-produced-if-delete-is-u

Comment: Always pair malloc with free, new with delete and use delete [] for arrays allocated with new. Otherwise you're entering the land of undefined behavior, or the land of pain as I personally call it.

Answer (score 1):

The actual crash happened on this line:

```
15:     delete this->string;
```

The crash happened due to to call to `abort` inside `__libc_message`. That last routine printed a message to your standard error, and the message looked something like

```
*** glbc detected: double free or heap corruption at ...  ***
```

Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/): they'll point you straight at the problem.

> I do not understand why the line 16 would result in that call stack.

When you are looking at call stack that led to the `raise` system call, you need to understand that the `CALL` instruction puts the address of the **next** instruction to be executed on the stack, before transferring control to the called procedure, and it is that next instruction that GDB shows you in the `backtrace` (all debuggers do that). That next instruction may be on the current line, the next line, or 20 lines down.

Comment: Please, see my comment/question at Tony The Lion's answer. And yes, I intend to use Valgrind to peel that onion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It points to the next line that is *about* to be executed, which is line 16 in your case, the last executed statement/expression was line 15 and it crashed on that line.

Hard to tell from your posting what is wrong here though.

Comment: Please tell me I'm not crazy. Can it vary between pointing to the line being executed and the line *about* to be executed? Because I'm quite sure this is the first time I see that. Or, at least, this is the first time the interpretation of "line being executed" made no sense.

Comment: The debugger, any that I've used, always point to the line past the one just executed, when it has crashed. I'm not talking when you are stepping through it.

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing thing up then. I'll pay attention next time. Thanks!